# How to hide or remove a button from outlook Ribbon?

Tags: outlook, ribbonx

How to hide or remove button (**Office Add-ins**)  from `Ribbon`? this button appears when compose a new message?

I tried all the following methods, but no one of them works (with no error raised).

Applied this registry key;

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Options\WebExt]
"StoreButtonInRibbonHomeTabAllowed"=dword:00000000
```

Untick option `Add-ins` from customize ribbon @ Main Tabs.
Removed `Office Add-ins` from customize ribbon @ Compose Tools.

I am using office 2016.

[image]

Comment: Please stop re-posting the same questions there.

Comment: The registry key is valid according to the MS KB article mentioned in my post.

Comment: Eugene Astafiev , I post again because someone insist on close it (may be the old question contained vba tag , and I was not provided any code). Also this time even without vba tag , the same person want to close!!!

Answer (score 0):

The changes in the windows registry may not apply immediately. Here is what the [How To Disable GET ADD-INS Button in Outlook](https://www.urtech.ca/2019/07/solved-how-to-disable-get-add-ins-button-in-outlook/) article states:

> Close Outlook and force a replication use GPUDATE /FORCE (not as an Admin because this is a local user) or reboot and you will see that the GET ADD-INS button is not just disabled, it is removed all together.  Note that we have noticed that the first time Outlook is started it takes an extra minute or two, which is very strange but acceptable.

Read more about the windows registry key in the [Update adds the Store button to the Home tab ribbon in Outlook 2013](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-adds-the-store-button-to-the-home-tab-ribbon-in-outlook-2013-6c750051-3ea0-f742-4326-9053a5dafbea) article.

Comment: It doesn't work, I don't blame you.

Comment: Have you tried to reboot the machine?

Comment: Surely I did, and the provided link on your answer about the button on `Home Tab`, but mu question about the button appears when I `compose a new message`.